# Elegant way to create global constant class

Tags: java, constants

I am new to Java and am wondering how to create in an elegant way a global object whose members are constant. One way to do this is:

```
public class Global {
    public final static String NAME = "John Doe";
    public final static int AGE = 100;
}
```

and then calling it outside as

```
import Global;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int age = Global.AGE; // works fine; age cannot be modified
}
```

The only issue is: I have a lot of variables in this class that I'm copying from a text file and adding the keywords "static", "public", and "final" is cumbersome and makes it look ugly. I know it's not a big issue, but I would like a more elegant solution to this. Any ideas? I have tried nested classes but could not figure out to have it behave correctly.

Comment: Switch languages.

Comment: use an interface, the variables declared in an interface are implicitly public static and final.

Comment: @akshayapandey With the caveat that this is often considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @emphasent have a look at `lombok`. Specifically `@UtilityClass` annotation. This will reduce your boiler plate code.

Comment: @DaveNewton what lang would you recommend? :)

Comment: *I'm copying from a text* just keep them inside `.properties` for house keeping

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Well, the original data file is a `.properties` file, which is fine. But importing it using a custom read function and transforming the data type makes it look even uglier. Functionally, it's alright, but aesthetically, not so much.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the comment. I am new to this massive project which has been going on in Java for more than 5 years, so I cannot hope to switch language.

Comment: @emphasent Then just write Java. "Adding keywords" is a keyboard macro or search-and-replace and is irrelevant. Java will always look ugly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you will handle only constants you can declare your class as **final class** and define a **private constructor** - Doing that, you avoid instantiation (the assertion error will make the class safe even if they try to instantiate the class using reflection), this is an elegant way to consolidate your constants in a class.

```
public final class Global {
    public static final String NAME = "John Doe";
    public static final int AGE = 100;
}

private Global() {
    //this prevents even the native class from 
    //calling this constructor as well :
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

**Advantages**:

- Since the required static memebers are imported statically, the class namespace is not polluted.
- The compiled code has one fewer binary compatibility constraint (that “class implements Constants Interface”).
- Because static imports apply only to the current file (and not the whole class hierarchy), it is easier to discover where each static member is declared.
- Run-time and compile-time semantics are more closely aligned when using static imports instead of constants interfaces.
- If required, static blocks can be declared.

Since some answers are suggesting using the interface, I suggest you check out this article [Why the Constant Interface Pattern Should Be Discouraged](https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-why-the-constant-interface-pattern-is-disc). If you can check out the Effective Java book will be a good reference as well.

Comment: While this is an alright description of why final classes are useful, it does nothing to solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***interface*** also

```
public interface Global {
     String NAME = "John Doe";
     int AGE = 100;
}
```

Comment: You can also use a global.properties file. Properties file have key value pair.
NAME=John Doe
AGE=100

Both Key and Value will be String. Retrieve the value where you require using the getProperty("Key") method from the Properties class (type of Map). check how to use Properties to read the file and load the data.

remember, all data will be fetched as String, so you have do the necessary conversions for int/long/double

Comment: Having constants in an interface is considered an antipattern, the interface is to implement different types, not a container of constants. Check out this article: https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-why-the-constant-interface-pattern-is-disc

Comment: @PriyakDey That is exactly the current implementation. Like I said in the OP, it's functionally alright but is just an aesthetic issue. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.